# Drag and drop grouping windows taskbar

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop, taskbar

I'm an avid user of the Opera browser. I really love the feature where I can drag and drop tabs on top of each other and have them grouped.

How can I get this same feature for the windows 7 taskbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group all the related task on Task bar. You can set the property of "Taskbar Buttons" by following the steps:

```
1. Right click on the task bar and select Properties option
2. On the dialog select TaskBar
3. Select "Always combine, hide lables" from Taskbar Buttons dropdown.
```

[image]

**And I think there is no any way to group related tasks by drag and drop in Windows 7.**

Comment: I spent some time searching but gave up.. Am pretty sure it doesn't exist (yet)

Comment: Yes it does not exists. So feel free to vote/accept thisanswer if you question has got the answer.